# iOS Resolutions for iPhone & iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile

I know this sort of a quesiton gets asked a lot but I've read a lot of answers and none of them quite answer my problem.

I'm setting up a game project and I'd like to support:

iPhone 5 and upward.
iPad (all)

So I've got quite a lot of confusion around the Resolution of the devices and the logical resolution. Some answers to my question give recommended dimensions which are the Resolution of certain devices and others give the logical resolution.

What I want to do is request two image sizes from my artists and then allow the devices to scale down.

So if I want to support iPads that have a 3:4 aspect ratio. Should my target resolution be:

2048x2732 (Resolution)
1024x1366 (Logical Resolution)

And similarly for iPhones with a 9:16 aspect ratio. Should ym target resolution be:

1242x2208 (Resolution)
414x736 (Logical Resolution)

The iPhone is actually a bit more confusing because I've read that the resolution actually gets scaled down to 1920x1080 so perhaps I should be targetting that?

Answer (score 1):

See this link:
http://www.kylejlarson.com/blog/iphone-6-screen-size-web-design-tips/
There is a graphic showing: rendered pixels, physical pixels, pixels per inch, etc. for all iPhone sizes. (iPhone 7 models are the same as iPhone6)

> iPhone Rendered Pixels – This is the full number of pixels that are
> being rendered. This is the value you get when you apply the
> multiplier (1x, 2x, 3x) the device uses to the screen size in points.
> If you’re creating an image and want it at the max resolution, this is
> the size you’d use. I’ve also written an article on Retina images if
> you’d like to learn more

So 1242 x 2208 would be the target size in your second example.